# Why am I not able to open SQL Server Instace's backup folder? How can I give permission to windows account to access this folder?

Tags: sql-server

Context: I have a SQL Server Instance which can be connected through windows authentication. But, I am unable to open the Backup folder it contains. I want to know why I can not open this folder.

Adding Location of the folder just to give an idea
 [image]

Comment: Because YOU, as whatever account you use to log into windows, do not have permissions. This has nothing to do with sql server, it's just basic windows permissions.

Comment: How can I give permissions to my windows login account to access this?

Comment: For the record it's trickier than some have let on. For me, "effective access" already said I had access (under advanced security settings on security tab). Because my user WAS an administrator, and administrator had full access. But I had to "Enable Inheritance". Which is not something I'm able to disable now, but now I have access. [Correction: I can use Disable Inheritance button if I first click and cancel out of "change owner", so clearly this stuff is not all working, and it IS tricky]

Comment: Like @JoshSutterfield what worked for me was enabling inheritance under Properties > Security > Advanced > "Enable Inheritance". My user was also a member of the "Administrators" group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: To use this answer, you need to login with administrator user into your system.

I followed following steps to get access:

1. Right click on the folder you want to get access and select properties.
2. Click on Security Tab.
3. Click on edit button.
4. Click Add
5. Click Advanced
6. Click Find Now
7. In the search results, select the users or groups you want to provide access.
8. Click Ok and then Apply.

You should be able to open access after following the above steps.

Comment: thanks for adding answer. You should be having sufficient privileges to do this. Otherwise, either the owner of the folder or the administrator has to do this for you.

Comment: That's Right. As I logged in with the Administrator user, I did not face any problem. I will mention this point as well.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have permissions on that folder. Ask the person, who is having administrator privileges in the server to give you access to that folder.

1. Administrator has to right click folder:`c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER2019\MSSQL\Backup` -> Sharing -> Advanced Sharing -> check Share this folder -> Permissions -> Add -> Your domain account -> Give Read Permissions -> OK -> OK

Once he gives access, you will be able to access the folder contents.

Comment: Thank you. I gave folder level permissions using security tab. Iam able to open now

Comment: cool. Mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future

Comment: I didn't use your answer. Shall I still mark it as answer?

Comment: then, please add your own answer and mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future.